# How to declare array from STDOUT in Buildspec, Codebuild, AWS

Tags: shell, array, aws

**I'm having a problem with declaring array from STDOUT in Buildspec, which is part of Codebuild in AWS.**
Buildspec using Pure Bourne Shell, so I can't use this line in code `declare -a available_envs=($(eb list --all))` or `available_envs=($(eb list --all))`

```
some build command...

eb list --all # list all created env in Elastic Beanstalk

declare -a available_envs=($(eb list --all)) # <<< here is a problem because I can't create array this way.
echo ${available_envs[@]} # <<< checking if variabla have all available env 

if [[ ${available_envs[*]} =~ 'develop' ]]; then
    echo 'Develop environment is allready created.'
    else
        echo "Creating Develop environment..."
        eb create develop
fi

some build command...
```

Thank you in advance.

---

Edit:

Output of command `eb list --all`

```
develop
production
stage
```

---

Solution:
Thx @faho for change of view.

I trim output a little before `grep` command

```
some build command...
envs=$(eb list --all | tr -d " \t\r" | tr -d [*] | grep "develop")
echo ${envs}

if [ "${envs}" = "develop" ]; then
        echo 'Develop environment is already created.'
        else
                echo "Creating Develop environment..."
fi
some build command...
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of the output the `eb list --all` command produces.  You can edit the output to disguise sensitive information.

Comment: `sh` doesn't have arrays so you'll need to find some other way of representing the data. In finding a solution, questions that would arise will include "can the data items contain spaces or other non-printing characters?"

Comment: @SottoVoce post is edited. I forgot to include it. Thx for reminder.

Comment: @roaima Thank you for comment. I know that ```sh``` can't create arrays this way, but I'm missing the solution for quite a few day now. That is why I post this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posix sh has neither arbitrary array variables nor `[[ .. ]]` conditionals. It has the positional arguments, `$@`, but setting that (with `set`) won't help you much because your comparison here won't work either.

So this requires a different way of thinking. You need to figure out what you want to do with this output and act accordingly.

As your code currently stands, you could just do

```
if eb list --all | grep -q develop; then
```

If you need the output again and want to not call `eb list --all` again, you could save it to a variable as one string and then use it later, like

```
envs=$(eb list --all)

if printf '%s\n' "$envs" | grep -q develop; then
```

(note: `grep -q develop` will match any line that has the substring "develop". If that's not wanted you might want `grep -q '^develop$'`)

Comment: I don't have enough points for like. After I gather enough points I will come back and give full validation. Once more, thank you for your help :)